# jQuery How to make an karaoke effect on text?

Tags: jquery, text, colors, transition

Does anyone know how I can make a karaoke effect with jQuery, on text?
It's the input of a user and will only consist of one word.
The user adds some input, and when you click add, 
the input adds to a output div.
The effect should appear on the output. Its only the effect.

[jsfiddle.net/cx5jZ](http://jsfiddle.net/opoe/cx5jZ/)

My question to you is;
How do I do this?
If yes, how can I make the user adjust the speed of the transition?

Comment: Is this actually going to be used for karaoke, or do you just want to simulate the visual effect? I mean, by adjusting the time, to you simply mean the transition from the entire text being blue, to the entire text being red, or would you need to be able to set the durations segment-based, syllable by syllable?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I just want to simulate the visual effect. The input will not be more than one word. So from the first to the last character. So the transition would be from the first to the last character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made this up: http://jsfiddle.net/bPGZT/.

Comment: Thats a nice solution and you understand what I want, but the input the input comes from the user. it won't be more than one word

Comment: Only a slight change is necessary: http://jsfiddle.net/bPGZT/1/. I don't know anything about karaoke so please bear with me if this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This is exactly what i want but, the input (val) has to come from an input field and when the submit button is pressed, the effect appears on the word.

Comment: Look http://jsfiddle.net/cx5jZ/ The user adds some input, and then when you click play, the effect should appear on the input

Comment: I understand that, but do you want a fixed time interval (e.g. 1 second) between each character? My example uses different time intervals between the letters/words. Because the user would have to supply the intervals as well.

Comment: Well a fixed time interval would be better, but if it's easier and less 'heavy' to use diffrent time intervals that's okay!

Comment: Thanks that works great! Look; http://jsfiddle.net/Dx5Wa/ Just one more thing, how can I let the user increase the speed, of this transition?

Comment: An `<input type="range">` is applicable perhaps: http://jsfiddle.net/Dx5Wa/1/. Change it and press Play again, and see :)

Answer (score 3):

I made a more complex example based on pimvdb's, hope someone find it usefull :D

[jQuery Karaoke](http://jsfiddle.net/bPGZT/47/)

cheers!